# What does imresizemex do in Matlab imresize function?

Tags: matlab

I was trying to create an image resize code using C to do exactly what imresize.m in Matlab does. I stuck at the line calling imresizemex in imresize.m. It seems that imresizemex is a compiled machine code that can only be called in Matlab (I found it as imresizemex.mexw64 file in a Matlab private folder, no source code available). I also tried to call it in C, but failed. Does anyone know where to find the source code for imresizemex? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a compiled internal function and the source is very likely stored at The MathWorks, good luck getting it.

Comment: @excaza Thanks! I do checked on MathWorks. Some people have the similar question, but no answers to it. :(

Comment: There are plenty of "hidden" codes inside the build-in functions.Otherwise MATLAB was  an open source... :)

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out ^ ^. It does the weighted multiplication and sum part of the cubic convolution interpolation. Here's my Matlab code replacing imresizemex. Although almost 6 seconds slower, it produces exactly the same result.

```
function outimg=reducesize(inimg, weights,indices,dim)

% reduce first dimension 
reduce1=zeros(dim(1),size(inimg,2));
weight1=weights{1};
index1=indices{1};
for i=1:size(inimg,2)
    for j=1:dim(1)
        w11=weight1(j,:);
        ind11=index1(j,:);
        B=double(inimg(ind11,i)); 
        v=w11.*B';
        reduce1(j,i)=sum(v);
    end
end

% reduce second dimension 
reduce2=zeros(dim(1),dim(2));
weight2=weights{2};
index2=indices{2};
for i=1:dim(1)
    for j=1:dim(2)
        w22=weight2(j,:);
        ind22=index2(j,:);
        B=reduce1(i,ind22);
        v=w22.*B;
        reduce2(i,j)=sum(v);
    end
end

outimg=round(reduce2);
```

Comment: This is a very useful answer. Two comments to help improve your answer. Your function has a different syntax compared to imresizemex. Perhaps you could add a bit of documentation? My second comment is that I don't get a binary match using the rice.png example in the documentation of  imresize.m,  when I try to downsample by a factor of 4, I get off-by-one errors (which is fine by me). Both these comments are based on R2016b. Thanks for sharing your solution!